# Удаление из бинарного дерева.Потеря указателя на главный корень

Tags: c, структуры, дерево

```
      if (pCur7 != NULL && (pCur7->left == deletable || pCur7->right==deletable) )
        {

            BinTree* pCur8 = Head;
            pCur8 = deletable->right;
            if (pCur8->left == NULL)
            {
                BinTree* pCur9 = findparent(deletable->data_field);
                if (pCur9->left == deletable)
                {
                    pCur8 = deletable->right;
                    pCur9->left = pCur8;
                    pCur8->left = deletable->left;
                    free(deletable);
                    return;
                }
                if (pCur9->right == deletable)
                {
                    pCur8 = deletable->right;
                    pCur9->right = pCur8;
                    pCur8->left = deletable->left;
                    free(deletable);
                    return;
                }
            }
            while (pCur8->left != NULL)
            {
                pCur8 = pCur8->left;
            }
            if (pCur8->right != NULL)
            {
                BinTree* ParentOfpCur8 = findparent(pCur8->data_field);
                ParentOfpCur8->left = pCur8->right;
                pCur8->right = NULL; 
            }
            pCur8->left = deletable->left;
            pCur8->right = deletable->right;
            /*BinTree* pCur9 = pCur8;
            while (1)
            {
                if (pCur9 != NULL)
                {
                    pCur8 = pCur9;
                }
                else break;
                pCur9 = findparent(pCur9->data_field);

            }
            Head = pCur8;*/
            free(deletable);
            return;
        }


    } 

 }
```

Пытаясь удалить узел поддерева(не главный корень,с которого начинается дерево его процедура работает) с двумя потомками из бинарного дерева,столкнулся с проблемой - не получается сохранить указатель на корень, а тот , который можно сохранить, не отображает изменения после замены узла на самый левый из правого поддерева(о его правом потомке тоже позаботился).То есть вопрос следующий:как сохранить указатель на главный корень дерева, если в процессе удаления происходят изменения с деревом,а переменная этим изменениям не подвержена, а значит в ней не хранится информация о сделанных перестановках.Саму переменную держу глобально.Просто в итоге хочется сделать traverse и увидеть результат удаления

```
struct BinTree
{
    int data_field=0;
    BinTree* left;
    BinTree* right;
};
BinTree* Head = NULL;
```

Comment: первое: `BinTree` - это не дерево, а нода. Где структура дерева? Второе: что за код вверху? Это функция или часть кода в `main`? Третье: что такое ваши pCur7 и тому подобное?